# Undefined error I can't figure out

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hey guys...having a math problem. Trying to layout a grid of gray boxes which I want to load thumbnails on top of. I keep getting an error when trying to load the 4th thumbnail. If you remove the 4th person node in the xml it works, but adding the 4th gives me an error?

Code is below.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class People extends MovieClip
    {

        public function People() 
        {
            draw();
        }

        public function draw():void
        {
            var colors:Array = [0xFF0000, 0x009900];
            var rows:Array = [];

            var xml:XML  = new XML("<data><navitem><person>person1</person><person>person2</person><person>person3</person><person>person4</person></navitem><navitem><person>person1</person><person>person2</person></navitem></data>");

            var j;
            var i;

            for (i in xml.navitem) {
                rows.push(new MovieClip());
                var totRows:Number = 0;
                for (j in xml.navitem[i].person) {
                    if(j % 3 == 1){
                        totRows++
                    }
                }

                if (totRows == 0) {
                    totRows = 1
                }

                rows[i].grid = createGrid(3, totRows, 85, 85,25, 25);
                for (j in rows[i].grid) {
                    var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
                    with (mc) {
                        graphics.beginFill(0, .5);
                        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 85, 85);
                        graphics.endFill();
                    }
                    mc.x = rows[i].grid[j].x;
                    mc.y = rows[i].grid[j].y;
                    rows[i].addChild(mc);
                }
                // add the people
                for (j in xml.navitem[i].person) {
                    var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
                    with (mc) {
                        graphics.beginFill(colors[i], .5);
                        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 85, 85);
                        graphics.endFill();
                    }
                    mc.x = rows[i].grid[j].x;
                    mc.y = rows[i].grid[j].y;
                    rows[i].addChild(mc);
                }

                addChild(rows[i]);
                rows[i].y = i > 0 ? rows[(i - 1)].y + rows[(i - 1)].height + 25 : 0;
            }

        }

        private function createGrid($columns:int, $rows:int, $xSpacing:int, $ySpacing:int, $xPadding:int, $yPadding:int, $leftToRight:Boolean = true):Array
        {
            var arr:Array = new Array();
            var pt:Point;
            var row:Number;
            var col:Number;
            var num:int = ($columns * $rows);

            for (var i:int = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                pt = new Point();

                if ($leftToRight)
                {
                    row = (i % $columns);
                    col = Math.floor(i / $columns);

                    pt.x = (row * ($xSpacing + $xPadding));
                    pt.y = (col * ($ySpacing + $yPadding));
                }
                else
                {
                    row = (i % $rows);
                    col = Math.floor(i / $rows);

                    pt.x = (col * ($xSpacing + $xPadding));
                    pt.y = (row * ($ySpacing + $yPadding));
                }

                arr.push(pt);
            }

            return arr;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have hard coded the number of columns to 3

```
rows[i].grid = createGrid(3, totRows, 85, 85,25, 25);
```

Change it to:

```
rows[i].grid = createGrid(xml.navitem[i].person.length(), totRows, 85, 85,25, 25);
```

---

Btw, consider using

```
for(i = 0; i < xml.navitem.length(); i++)
```

instead of

```
for (i in xml.navitem)
```

and typing the variables like `var i:Number;`

Currently values of `i` are strings like `"0"`, `"1"` - it will lead to errors at unexpected points and those might be hard to debug.

update:
Initialize number of rows to one instead of zero:

```
var totRows:Number = 1;
```

Comment: Actually I have to leave it at 3 because I only want 3 columns in the grid. But typesetting the variables is a MUST.

Comment: you are initializing the number of rows to zero - make it one and it would work. Currently, with four items, number of rows passed to creategrid method is 1 instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer. Had to change up the conditional statements as such:

```
var totRows:int;
if (xml.navitem[i].person.length() % 3 == 0){
    totRows = xml.navitem[i].person.length() / 3;
} else {
totRows = xml.navitem[i].person.length() / 3 + 1;
}
```